# Tracking by id in url with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, stat

I want to track views for stories on my site. I want to use Google analytics to do this. Off the bat Im thinking of doing this:

```
pageTracker._trackEvent('Story', 'View', 'Title of story');
```

But I also would prefer to track with the story id as well that is passed in the url. So if I want to run a report in GA I would like to have the option of getting stats by story title or by story id that is passed via url. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GA by default does not strip parameters from the URL when _trackPageview is triggered, so you will see unique pages show up in your reports.  For example, these two will show up as separate entries:

```
/somePage.html?id=1
/somePage.html?id=2
```

edit:

Okay, you can use this to get whatever url parameter you want:

```
function getParam (n) {
  var x=new RegExp("[\\?&]"+n.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]")+"=([^&#]*)");
  var r=x.exec(window.location.href);  
  return(r==null)?'':r[1] ;
}
// example 
var story = getParam('story'));
```

now `story` has whatever value the story=xxx URL parameter value is, and you can use `story` as your category value in your event tracking argument

Comment: I guess what I was looking for was a way to go to a category like stories and bring up all impressions/views for a specific story id.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you recommend putting that in the label instead of the category?

Comment: @John: Only you can answer that.  I personally see little value in tracking the ID in the first place, especially since you are tracking the title.  But in general, I probably would make it the label instead of the category, as all your story ids fall under the broader *category* of being a story.

Comment: Can GA track a URL by any param you specify in the URL?

Comment: @heinkasner I'm not sure I understand what you mean.. please post a separate question and provide more details/example of what you want to do